Allow Free shipping If there is only a specific product type or if subtotal reaches a minimal amout
I have a script that create a progress bar to show "Spend another XX € for free shipping!" based on a minimal amount to be spent, but I would like to avoid this text if there are ONLY products in cart from a specific product type. This because people could also buy an "Appointment" product, that are not physical products, but are under the custom product type "Appointment".
Here is my current code:
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'ecommercehints_free_shipping_for_specific_products', 10, 2 );
function ecommercehints_free_shipping_for_specific_products($rates, $package, $order) {
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        // Get an instance of the WC_Product Object from the WC_Order_Item_Product
        $product = $item->get_product();
        $cart_total = WC()->cart->get_subtotal();

        if( $product->is_type('Appointment')  ){
            echo 'You\'ve unlocked free shipping!';
        } else if ( $cart_total < 50 ) {
            unset( $rates['free_shipping:21'] ); // The shipping method radio button value
        }
        break; // We stop the loop and keep the first item
    }
    return $rates;
}   

// Show 'Spend another X amount' on checkout.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'ecommercehints_checkout_page_progress_bar', 10 );
function ecommercehints_checkout_page_progress_bar() {
    $cart_total = WC()->cart->get_subtotal();
    $cart_remaining = 50 - $cart_total;
    $product = $item->get_product();

    if ($cart_total < 50 ) {
        echo 'Spend another ' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . $cart_remaining . ' for free shipping!<br><progress id="freeshippingprogress" max="50" value="'.$cart_total.'"></progress>';
    } else if ( $product->is_type('Appointment') {
        echo 'You\'ve unlocked free shipping!';
    }      
}


There are some mistakes in your code like:

the $order variable doesn't exist for woocommerce_package_rates filter hook.
Here you need to check cart items, but not order items.

Also, you need to be sure that "Appointment" is a valid product type. In general, product types are always in lowercase, so I used "appointment" (in lowercase) below.
Try the following revised code:
// Conditional function that checks if there are only "appointment" product types in cart
function has_only_appointments() {
    $others_found = false; // Initializing

    // Loop through cat items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        if ( ! $item['data']->is_type('appointment') ) {
            $others_found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return !$others_found;
}

// Filter shipping  methods
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'ecommercehints_free_shipping_for_specific_products', 10, 2 );
function ecommercehints_free_shipping_for_specific_products( $rates, $package ) {
    // check if there are only "appointment" product types in cart
    if( has_only_appointments()  ){
        return $rates;
    }
    
    // If there is shippable products remove free shipping if cart subtotal is under specific amount 
    if ( WC()->cart->get_subtotal() < 50 ) {
        unset( $rates['free_shipping:21'] ); // The targeted Free shipping method rate ID
    }
    return $rates;
}

// Show 'Spend another X amount' on checkout.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'ecommercehints_checkout_page_progress_bar', 10 );
function ecommercehints_checkout_page_progress_bar() {
    $subtotal = WC()->cart->get_subtotal();

    // check if there are only "appointment" product types in cart or If cart subtotal is up to 50
    if( has_only_appointments( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) || $subtotal >= 50 ){
        echo __("You've unlocked free shipping!", "woocommerce");
    } elseif  ( $subtotal < 50 ) {
        printf( __('Spend another %s for free shipping!', 'woocommerce'), wc_price( 50 - $subtotal ) );
        printf('<br><progress id="freeshippingprogress" max="50" value="%d"></progress>', intval($subtotal) );
    }    
}

It should work…
Important: Empty your cart to refresh the shipping methods cached data.

Addition (for virtual products):
Now as your custom product type "Appointments" is not a "Physical" product, it should be "virtual" by default…
So you can try the following instead:
// Conditional function that checks if there are only virtual products in cart
function has_only_virtual_products() {
    $physical_found = false; // Initializing

    // Loop through cat items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        if ( ! $item['data']->is_virtual() ) {
            $others_found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return !$others_found;
}

// Filter shipping  methods
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'ecommercehints_free_shipping_for_specific_products', 10, 2 );
function ecommercehints_free_shipping_for_specific_products( $rates, $package ) {
    // check if there are only virtual products in cart
    if( has_only_virtual_products()  ){
        return $rates;
    }
    
    // If there is shippable products remove free shipping if cart subtotal is under specific amount 
    if ( WC()->cart->get_subtotal() < 50 ) {
        unset( $rates['free_shipping:21'] ); // The targeted Free shipping method rate ID
    }
    return $rates;
}

// Show 'Spend another X amount' on checkout.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'ecommercehints_checkout_page_progress_bar', 10 );
function ecommercehints_checkout_page_progress_bar() {
    $subtotal = WC()->cart->get_subtotal();

    // check if there are only virtual products in cart or If cart subtotal is up to 50
    if( has_only_virtual_products() || $subtotal >= 50 ){
        echo __("You've unlocked free shipping!", "woocommerce");
    } elseif  ( $subtotal < 50 ) {
        printf( __('Spend another %s for free shipping!', 'woocommerce'), wc_price( 50 - $subtotal ) );
        printf('<br><progress id="freeshippingprogress" max="50" value="%d"></progress>', intval($subtotal) );
    }    
}

It could work…
Important: Empty your cart to refresh the shipping methods cached data.

Amazing! thank you! eventually is possible to add an extra condition if there are all appointment or only one appointment write a tex or better hide all, and keep the >= and the < conditions. Looks like to be more logical imho

I edited your solution with a code to separate all conditions; could it works?

You should go through your code line and fix few thigs like " $order variable doesn't exist for woocommerce_package_rates filter hook."
that should be on a label line

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
